# Visual Studio debug log (like logcat in Android)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug a C#/.Net program in Visual Studio 2010 but it's timing-sensitive so breakpoints mess it up.   So I just want to log certain events and their relative times and watch them as my program is running.

Does Visual Studio (or C# or .Net) have any facility for writing to a log file that Visual Studio can display as a debug window?

When I do Android development in Eclipse I can take advantage of their Log class and insert lines that looks like this in my code:

```
  Log.d("Label1", "Hit checkpoint X");
```

And they will appear along with time/date stamps in the LogCat window which is displayed along with other windows in Eclipse.

What's the closest equivalent to this in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: you have quick watch there in visual studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint that doesn't actually break, but outputs a log message instead.  Just set a breakpoint, then right click on the breakpoint and select "When Hit...".

From that dialog select "Print a message" and "continue execution"

[image: Dialog screenshot]

Comment: Where do the messages appear?

Comment: In the Output window (View -> Output)

Comment: Is there any way to embed or display the contents of local variables in the message?

Comment: Yes, as long as the variable is in scope, just do as the dialog says, surround the variable name in braces: `Current value is:  {myVariable}`

Comment: oh duh -  I didn't even notice that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really anything built in exactly like logcat, but there are lots of logging frameworks that you can use.

Personally, I like to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) and set up a UDP target for tracing/debugging within my configuration file along with a rule to forward all loggers to the target.  I think that NLog is easier to use than Log4Net (the .NET port of Log4j).  Once you do this you can create a logger from the manager and call the logger just like LogCat in android:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyClassTag");

logger.Trace("Something to log");
logger.Debug("Something to log");
logger.Info("Something to log");
logger.Warn("Something to log");
logger.Error("Something bad to log", exception);
logger.Fatal("Something bad to log", exception);
```

For listening to the UDP logging packets I use [Log2Console](https://log2console.codeplex.com/) which allows me to view them just like android's logcat viewer.

Comment: Let me know if you need some help setting this up.  It's pretty simple once you get it, but it does have a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: This seems like a lot of extra work and overhead, having to employ third-party tools and put stuff in the configuration file.    I'm surprised that a mature development environment like Visual Studio and .Net doesn't have this capability built-in.  heavyd's answer is a bit closer to what I need but I gave you a +1 for your effort.

Comment: @user316117 Yeah it is a bit surprising and I'm not a big fan of the method in heavyd's answer only because of how limited it is.  However, I completely see your point that it can be considered a bit heavy handed, but its footprint isn't too bad. It's a very nice framework that's pretty easy to use once you set up that single config file (just a bit of xml) that allows you to do exactly what you do with Logcat.

Comment: @JNYRanger is there any way you can share an XML file to do exactly this? It's the missing piece in the puzzle and NLog is kinda heavy to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @DARKGuy Sorry, I answered this question 6+ years ago and don't have any example material anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, this question was at the top of my Google search when looking for something similar (though it's 5 years old), so in case anyone else comes across it, this is the easiest method I've encountered:

```
Debug.WriteLine("hit checkpoint X");
```

It's included in System.Diagnostics, so you'll need a `using System.Diagnostics` at the top of your file, but that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Android Logcat Output** plugin:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LancelotChen.AndroidLogcatOutput

Visual Studio Tool Window Extension for Android Logcat Output & Filter

Inspired by NVidia Nsight Tegra.

To launch the logcat output window, use Menu

**View --> Other Windows --> Logcat Output**

[image]

Then the logcat output window will show.

[image]
On the left pane is filter list, you can add new filetr. Make one filter checked, the logs will be filtered.

Right-click on filter will bring out conext menu, which you can use to delete or edit filter settings.